# Why did the movie skip many of the rooms that guarded the Sorcerer's Stone?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the first Harry Potter movie, *The Sorceror's Stone*, it is seen that the filmmakers skipped many of the rooms that were shown in the book. They also changed the plot; for example, Hermione stays with Ron instead of going with Harry.

Why did they do this?

Comment: Probably time constraints, when adapting a book to a movie a lot of it has to get cut out otherwise the movie runtime will be to long. IF there is a series of challenges in succession of each other it is logical to remove some of those instead of more plot driven scenes.

Comment: Because most of the "traps" were stupid.

Answer (score 9):

Two rooms were cut:

- **The Troll**
  Nothing happens in this room as the troll has already been defeated. It serves no purpose to plot or character, and would require some dull explanation of why it's there and what happened.
- **The Potions**
  This was apparently cut for time or pacing late in production, and appears as a deleted scene. As this was cut, Hermione cannot be blocked by this room, and so it would have to be changed so she stays with Ron instead of going forward and then back.

Comment: do you have a source that you are referring to?
If so, can you edit your question to show it?
Thanks!

Comment: @C0D3X for what? These are observations based on the book and the DVD release. I'm not quoting or assigning intent to anyone.

Comment: I'm actually for sources and not observations
Thanks for letting me know though!

Comment: I wouldn't say the troll room serves no plot purpose - it shows that Quirrell was involved with preparing the defences, and explains how he was able to find the way past the other rooms.